# vtk chart - how to draw axis labels at the end of axis lines?

Tags: c++, vtk, qvtkwidget

Is it possible to draw axis labels at the end of labels?
See picture for details:

http://habrastorage.org/files/94f/41a/b18/94f41ab1897a4bde815644bf287b4af9.png

If it is possible, how?

```
vtkNew<vtkContextView> contextView;

vtkNew<vtkTable> table;
vtkNew<vtkChartXY> chart;
vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> timeAxis;
vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> realDataAxis;
vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> measuredDataAxis;

// ...

contextView->SetInteractor(vtkWidget->GetInteractor());
vtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(contextView->GetRenderWindow());

timeAxis->SetName("t");
realDataAxis->SetName("x(t)");
measuredDataAxis->SetName("x*(t)");

table->AddColumn(timeAxis.Get());
table->AddColumn(realDataAxis.Get());
table->AddColumn(measuredDataAxis.Get());

chart->SetShowLegend(true);
auto legend = chart->GetLegend();
legend->GetLabelProperties()->SetFontSize(14);
legend->GetLabelProperties()->SetFontFamilyToTimes();

auto xAxis = chart->GetAxis(vtkAxis::BOTTOM);
xAxis->SetTitle(QApplication::translate("DataSetChartWidget", "t").toStdString());

auto xTitleProps = xAxis->GetTitleProperties();
xTitleProps->SetFontSize(14);
xTitleProps->SetFontFamilyToTimes();

auto xLabelProps = xAxis->GetLabelProperties();
xLabelProps->SetFontSize(14);
xLabelProps->SetFontFamilyToTimes();

auto yAxis = chart->GetAxis(vtkAxis::LEFT);
yAxis->SetTitle(QApplication::translate("DataSetChartWidget", "x(t), x*(t)").toStdString());

auto yTitleProps = yAxis->GetTitleProperties();
yTitleProps->SetFontSize(14);
yTitleProps->SetFontFamilyToTimes();

auto yLabelProps = yAxis->GetLabelProperties();
yLabelProps->SetFontSize(14);
yLabelProps->SetFontFamilyToTimes();

contextView->GetScene()->AddItem(chart.Get());
```

And code for plotting:

```
auto realPlot = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::LINE);
realPlot->SetInputData(table.Get(), 0, 1);

auto measuredPlot = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::POINTS);
measuredPlot->SetInputData(table.Get(), 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the vertical and horizontal alignment of the axis title.

e.g.

```
myVtkChart->GetAxis(0)->GetTitleProperties()->SetJustificationToLeft();
```

in your case it should be sufficient to call

```
xTitleProps->SetJustificationToRight();
yTitleProps->SetJustificationToLeft();
```

but it seems that the title width is not scaled to the axes length.
This means its probably necessary to put some white spaces  into your title string to get the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question ... i have changed the answer.